# Raster Mosaic fault using R

Tags: r, modis, mosaic

I'm trying to mosaic two raster images using R. I used this script:

```
setwd("D:\\Modis EVI\\")
raster_dir <-    "D:\\Modis EVI\\"
r1 <- brick(paste(raster_dir,"evi8_stack.tif", sep=""))
r2 <- brick(paste(raster_dir,"evi9_stack.tif", sep=""))
m1 <- mosaic(r1, r2, fun=mean)
```

The script worked fine but the result mosaic has this black line, see picture

[image]

Any advice please on why I have this line, and how could it be removed?

Comment: You either have a real gap between your data or your rasters have a background value that is being assigned during the mosaic process. If you figure out what the background value is you can explicitly assign it a NA value.

Comment: what is the solution if there is a real gap?

Comment: You could fix it with a conditional focal function or interpolate the missing data.

Answer (score 1):

changing the function in the script to MAX, has solved the problem : 
m1 <- mosaic(r1, r2, fun=max)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar phenomenon mosaicing 203 tiles (7x29) into a single raster. The "line" was a row of NAs between tile rows 5 and 6. I hypothesize this was a memory allocation issue. There was no gap in the tiles (if I mosaiced two of the offending tiles from rows 5 and 6, no NA row would occur), nor was there a background value being assigned. Nor did changing the function help (i.e. fun=max).

After much debugging, my solution was to do two rounds of mosaicing, clearing memory in the process. Thus, I mosaiced 203 tiles to 3 three tiles, then those three tiles to one. No NA rows occurred in the final image. Clearly buggy behavior, thus my hypothesis that it was a memory issue - wish it were definitive though. In any case, my solution worked.